# Searching in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstableview, nssearchfield

I have an `NSMutableArray` that populates a `NSTableView`. It contains strings : `dog, cat, duck, cow, moose, nil`. I have a search bar above my NSTableView and would like to select the item in the tableview that has the closest match to the string I searched (in the searchbar). Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: Not sure, but is this an auto-complete question? http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

Comment: The first step is: Define what the closest match is. For example, what is the closest match to "z"? The closest match to "dowk"?

Answer (score 1):

You may calculate a distance measure between the search string and the strings in your table. Then pick the element with the smallest distance value.

One way to calculate a distance measure is by using the Levenshtein Distance Algorithm. An implementation can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/wewearglasses/1593632). It works in my case.

It is also possible to search for partial matches:

```
if ( [titleWord rangeOfString:searchWord options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].length > 0 )
```

Or, if you would like to find words that start as the search string:

```
if ( [titleWord.lowercaseString hasPrefix:searchWord.lowercaseString] )
```

Comment: How would I get the index of the string that is closest match to `searchWord`?

Comment: Once you have the string in your table identified that matches your search word best, you can use the method `indexOfObject` of your NSMutableArray.

Comment: do I put this if into like a for loop? how would I get titleword?

Comment: Yes, you can use a for loop to determine the string in your array that best matches your search word.